# How to fit points of big double values into a drawn coordinate system?

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinate-systems, points

I have a coordinate system (see the screenshot below) and want to place points on it. However the values of the points are greater than pixels of the panel (e.g x = 4415615.076; y = 113097.900). I can't figure out how to adapt drawing the lines to these huge numbers and how fit points into this coordinate system. Please suggest any solution.

```
private void CoordinateSystemPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    DrawAxes(g);

}
private void DrawAxes(Graphics g)
{
    var m0 = Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(coordinateSystemPanel.Width / 2, coordinateSystemPanel.Height / 2);
    g.Transform = Matrix3x2ToMatrix(m0);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, -coordinateSystemPanel.Width / 2, 0, coordinateSystemPanel.Width / 2, 0);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, 0, -coordinateSystemPanel.Height / 2, 0, coordinateSystemPanel.Height / 2);
    g.DrawString("X", this.Font, Brushes.LightBlue, coordinateSystemPanel.Width / 2 - 20, -20);
    g.DrawString("Y", this.Font, Brushes.LightBlue, 5, -coordinateSystemPanel.Height / 2 + 5);

    int tick = 50;
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat
    {
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    };

    for (int i = -200; i <= 200; i += tick)
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, i, -3, i, 3);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, -3, i, 3, i);
        SizeF sizeXTick = g.MeasureString(i.ToString(), this.Font);
        if(i!=0)
        {
            g.DrawString(i.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.LightBlue, i + sizeXTick.Width / 2, 4f, sf);
            g.DrawString((-i).ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.LightBlue, -3f, i - sizeXTick.Height / 2, sf);
        } else
        {
            g.DrawString("0", this.Font, Brushes.LightBlue, new PointF(i - sizeXTick.Width / 3, 4f), sf);
        }
    }
}

private Matrix Matrix3x2ToMatrix(Matrix3x2 m)
{
    return new Matrix(m.M11, m.M12, m.M21, m.M22, m.M31, m.M32);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a range of x, y values of points? Do you want to fit them inside your 200 * 200 graph or you want to fit your graph size. Do you accept simple stretching into graph or you want to keep proportions from points?

Comment: regarding the range - yes. I get a list of all points and can get a range with the help of min and max values. I want this coordinate system to be filled with points I provide and the beginning of x line should be  -(max value) and the end should be +(max value) respectively. And points should be placed correspondigly. I don't know exactly whether it's called scaling, so regardless of how big values are the points should be placed on this coordinate system.

Comment: you can find scaling coefficients as max(abs(points x)) / graph width and max(abs(points y)) / graph height (pseudocode) if you don't care about keeping original ratio.

Comment: You probably meant vice versa graph.width / point.x, but I got your idea. Thank you. But what if I want to save original ratio? I think if I scale it down by 100000, it will be completely different.